# Google Widget Links

Tags: html, css, google-sites, google-widget

I am working on a widget for a  google site and I've run into this little problem. If I have a html link `<a href="http://www.dw-picture.com/" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Home&nbsp;</a>` and an user clicks on the link it will open inside the widget itself, but if my html is `<a href="http://www.dw-picture.com/" target="_blank" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Home&nbsp;</a>` it will open a new link inside of the browser, is there a way to navigate inside the browser, not the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `target="_parent"` will solve the problem.